# Google charts Pie without data

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to use Google charts in my Polls' website. Everything works fine, until I have no votes to show ( for example, no one has answered the question). The chart doesn't even appear, as you can see in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/au9prxsg/3/

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     0],
      ['Eat',      0],
      ['Commute',  0],
      ['Watch TV', 0],
      ['Sleep',    0]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
         sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

[image]

I even put the property sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0.
Is it possible to have a pie chart with any data?

Comment: If there are not votes across any categories what exactly should it show? What percentage of a pie is "0"? Also, what does this have to do with highcharts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could test the dataTable to see if responses exist, then adjust what you display accordingly.

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     0],
      ['Eat',      0],
      ['Commute',  0],
      ['Watch TV', 0],
      ['Sleep',    0]
    ]);

    if(hasResponses(data, 1){
      ...
      [build your options array and draw you chart]
      ...
      }else{
      ...
      [display something else instead of the chart (i.e., a graphic or text indicating that the question has no responses).]
      }
  }


function hasResponses(datasource, column){
  var sumValues = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < datasource.getNumberOfRows(); ++i) {
    sumValues = sumValues + datasource.getValue(column, i);
    }
  if(sumValues > 0){
    return true;
    }else{
    return false;
    }
  }
```

This assumes that every respondent will provide a value > 0 for at least one activity (work, sleep, etc.), if not then the data collection (survey) should have a catch-all category (i.e., "other", etc.) that would allow you to force response to the question without affecting the integrity of the response.

Assuming your data is coming from some other database (not manually entered into javascript), a faster, simpler method may involve counting the number of responses in your data set before building your datatable in javascript.  Then, using a similar logic as above, display an alternative message if less than one response exists.

Answer (score 1):

Change perspective

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     0],
          ['Eat',      0],
          ['Commute',  0],
          ['Watch TV', 0],
          ['Sleep',    0],
          ['No activities or no response',    24]
        ]);
```

or

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work no response',     4.8],
          ['Eat no response',     4.8],
          ['Commute no response',     4.8],
          ['Watch TV no response',     4.8],
          ['Sleep no response',     4.8]
        ]);
```

Comment: simple and beautiful!

Answer (score 0):

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/au9prxsg/4/)

Works fine for me ? what is the error

`Add the js in the external js section`, and just copy the url there, it works

Comment: you all have data in your table, my problem is if you don't hava any data, every option at 0